# Trying to install SQL Server 2012 on win 7. Its a 64-bit machine. I get the following error

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, windows-7

> TITLE: Microsoft SQL Server 2012  Setup
>
> The following error has occurred:
>
> An error occurred during the installation of assembly 'Microsoft.VC80.ATL, version="8.0.50727.6229", publicKeyToken="1fc8b3b9a1e18e3b", processorArchitecture="x86",type="win32"'.
>   Please refer to Help and Support for more information.
>   HRESULT: 0x80070422.

Comment: what installer are you using? have you tried a newer one that includes the latest service pack?

Comment: Is your windows & fully patched and registered?  Do the OS and SQL architectures match (both 64 bit)?

Comment: Can't you install a newer version? SQL server 2012 is nearing end of support (or maybe already past it).

Comment: I am using SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe(11.0.5058.0). Yes my windows is up-to-date on windows updates and both OS and SQL arch are 64 bit.

Comment: I just found out that my updates even though are updated they magically appear back  as if they have not installed, i have cleared the windows\software distribution folders but they still are not getting installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with Windows update.The "Windows Module installer" service was disabled once i enabled it and cleared up all the updates in C:\Windows\software distribution folder, it started updating and when i install the sqlserver-2012 i dint get that error anymore.

This is where i found about the service.
https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/windows-update-error-80070422/372f6482-ff7c-4f92-858c-228b637bfae4